# preg_match unicode parsing

Tags: php, unicode, preg-match

I want to match a sub set of unicode/UTF-8 chars, (marked in yellow here http://solomon.ie/unicode/), from my research I came up with this:

```
// ensure it's valid unicode / get rid of invalid UTF8 chars
$text = iconv("UTF-8","UTF-8//IGNORE",$text);

// and just allow a basic english...ish.. chars through - no controls, chinese etc
$match_list = "\x{09}\x{0a}\x{0d}\x{20}-\x{7e}"; // basic ascii chars plus CR,LF and TAB 
$match_list .= "\x{a1}-\x{ff}"; // extended latin 1 chars excluding control chars
$match_list .= "\x{20ac}"; // euro symbol

if (preg_match("/[^$match_list]/u", $text) )
    $error_text_array[] = "<b>INVALID UNICODE characters</b>";
```

Testing seems to show it works as expected, but as a newbie to uniocde I'd be grateful if anyone here can spot any vulnerabilities I've overlooked.

Can I confirm that the hex ranges are matching unicode code points as opposed to the actual hex value (ie x20ac instead of xe282ac for the Euro symbol is correct)?

And can I mix literal characters and hex values like preg_match("/[^0-9\x{20ac}]/u", $text)?

Thanks,
Kevin

Note, I tried this question before but it was closed off - "better suited to codereview.stackexchange.com", but no response there so hope it's ok to try again in a much more concise format.

Answer (score 2):

I created a wrapper to test your code and I think it is secure in filtering characters you expected but your code will cause E_NOTICE when it found invalid UTF-8 characters. So I think you should add @ in the beginning of iconv line to suppress notices.

For the second question, it is ok to mix literal characters and hex values. You can also try that by yourself too. :)

```
<?php
function generatechar($char)
{
    $char = str_pad(dechex($char), 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $unicodeChar = '\u'.$char;
    return json_decode('"'.$unicodeChar.'"');
}
function test($text)
{   
    // ensure it's valid unicode / get rid of invalid UTF8 chars
    @$text = iconv("UTF-8","UTF-8//IGNORE",$text); //Add @ to surpress warning
    // and just allow a basic english...ish.. chars through - no controls, chinese etc
    $match_list = "\x{09}\x{0a}\x{0d}\x{20}-\x{7e}"; // basic ascii chars plus CR,LF and TAB
    $match_list .= "\x{a1}-\x{ff}"; // extended latin 1 chars excluding control chars
    $match_list .= "\x{20ac}"; // euro symbol

    if (preg_match("/[^$match_list]+/u", $text)  )
        return false;

    if(strlen($text) == 0)
        return false; //For testing purpose!
    return true;
}

for($n=0;$n<65536;$n++)
{
    $c = generatechar($n);
    if(test($c))
        echo $n.':'.$c."\n";
}
```

Comment: chalet16 - many thanks for that. I'll play with your test code when back in the office Monday. I have mixed the chars as per my example and it does seem to work ok, but was just checking to be sure:) Again many thanks for your efforts, Kevin

Comment: Hi, I got to try this now, it does work mostly as expected except that I seem to be returning true for u+d800 to u+dfff. I don't see where I'm going wrong on this. Also I notice you added the + metachar to my regexp - is that needed when wanteing to match ant char not in a list?

Comment: I just see that u+d800 to u+dfff are the surrogate pair - but that seems to be used in UTF-16, not 8? And the iconv should have stripped them?

Comment: Have you check for an empty string? u+d800 to u+dfff  has been strip and it would be change to empty string. ( for + metachar, i accidentally added it , it is not required at all)

Comment: Hi, I assume you mean the iconv would create the empty strings on that range? I commented it out, and did a return false on " " and NULL and still the same results. Thanks re the +, I was thinking I relay had missed something if that was needed!