# Matching a range of unicode characters

Tags: mysql, unicode

I want to do a query that matches anything containing the characters 0xFB50-0xFDFF (Arabic Presentation Forms-A) and 0xFE70-0xFEFF (Arabic Presentation Forms-B). I have tried various things, including simple REGEXP with those characters enclosed in [] with a dash in the middle (e.g., [ݐ-ݭ]) but it seems to return everything with Arabic in it, even if it's not in the "presentation form" range. I was wondering if there was something like:
  SELECT column FROM db WHERE CHAR(0xFE70) THROUGH CHAR(0xFEFF);

Obviously there is no "through" operator, but that's my pseudo-code :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer from another article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365160/preg-match-unicode-parsing). I decided MySQL's regex engine was not clever enough to do what I wanted to natively, so I used the PCRE functionality of PHP...

```
    $arabic_presentation_forms = "[\x{fb50}-\x{feff}]";
    preg_match("/$arabic_presentation_forms/u",$db_output);
```

Worked well.